# added certificate to java keystore, still error

Tags: java, security, ssl

Based on various web inputs, I have followed the following steps to add certificate to my local jdk keystore:

1. Downloaded the certificates by hitting the following command from a Linux host: openssl s_client -connect MyService:443 -showcerts
2. Copied the content between (and including) ------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-------- and --------END CERTIFICATE---------, saved it as C:\Java\jre\lib\security\cer1.cer
3. Typed: C:\Java\jre\bin>keytool -keystore C:\Java\jre\lib\security\cacerts -importcert -alias cer1 -file C:\Java\jre\lib\security\cer1.cer

This showed a message the certificate added successfully. Which i verified by using list command for keytool

4. Then i restarted my machine, and tried to run my Java program again, but still keep getting error:

"sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid     certification path to requested target"

JDK Used: 1.8.0_31, Windows 7

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two types of setup where we were able to make it work:

1. On one machine, the person installing the JDk had done some changes to the folder structure for installing Java and had the following structure: Java/jre/lib/security as well as Java/lib/security. We added certificates to cacerts of Java/lib/security and it started to work
2. On a second machine, where the user did the default istallation, the following folder structure existed: Java/jre_1.8/lib/security and Java/jdk_1.8/jre/lib/security. We updated cacerts at Java/jre_1.8/lib/security and it started to work (For some reason, updating cacartes at Java/jdk_1.8/jre/lib/security did not work)

Comment: And here is another thing, that worked on a colleagues machine. Post installation they had under C:\Program Files\Java - one jdk_1.8 folder created and one jre_1.8 folder. First we tried adding certificates in jdk_1.8/jre/lib/security/cacerts, did not work. Then we added certificates to jre_1.8/lib/security/cacerts - it worked. There was no jdk_1.8/lib/security folder on their machine (which actually existed on my machine)

Comment: i am still struggling in this i added the certificate still i am getting the error ..can you help me in this ... i m using AdoptOpenJDK 11... I am still not understood how two machines

Comment: @dhS can you please share your folder structure and show what's in your PATH variable. I want to ensure that you are using same java which you are adding certs to

Comment: I am really confused in this i updated the java and the certificate was successfully connecting yesterday, but today i found again it is giving the same exception, I am unable to understand how it was working yesterday and today it is not working. If you are online can we chat.

Comment: I'm using java 11 and adding at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17\lib\security\cacert certificate shows added but it doesn't work. pls help

Comment: @Ajeetkumar - For what its worth, are you able to confirm that your application is using the same JDK as above?

Comment: Hi @JavaTec, it was my mistake that I used wrong name of keystore as cacert instead of cacerts.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a JDK, adding it to the JRE truststore won't help. You need to add it to the truststore of the JRE that comes inside the JDK.

Comment: Hi EJP thank you for looking into this. Yes i added this to the JRE inside the JDK (i double checked that my class path is pointing to my JDK), but the error persists

Comment: `C:\Java\jre` is the installed JRE, not the one inside the JDK.

Comment: Actually the folder java is JDK only, i had named it as java earlier. It contains readme file which also confirms its JDK. it has its own bin, jre, lib etc. folders as well

Comment: Something hit and trial i tried seems to have worked: instead of updating cacerts of jdk/jre/lib/security, i instead updated the jdk/lib/security (no jre) and its working right now!!!! But really thank you EJP, that answer you posted got my thought process working and i tried to look at things from outside of book perspective. thank you for your time and effort!